# unable to drop column in dataframe, R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am reading an api using R and was able to retrieve the data, however, the data itself is retrieved in JSON format with what seems to be in 3 sections.

Converting the json data to a df using

```
fromJSON(data)
```

It was successful.

The next step was to drop the unnecessary columns, which is the my current issue and not able drop any columns to which I just recently found out how the data is formatted in the data frame.

```
lead <- GET("some api", add_headers(Authorization="Bearer some apikey"))
data <- content(lead,"text") #display the data looks something like below
```

[image]

The data seems to be formatted into 3 sections where I believe the issue is preventing columns to be dropped

```
$'data'
$included
$link
```

I've looked at multiple stackoverflow posts and r guides on dropping column name in df, but was unsuccessful

```
> df <- df[,-1]
Error in df[, -1] : incorrect number of dimensions

> df <- subset(df, select = -c("$'data'$id"))
Error in subset.default(df, select = -c("$'data'$id")) : 
  argument "subset" is missing, with no default
```

The end goal is to drop everything in $links, a few columns in $included, and a few columns in $data

Comment: Looks like you have `list`  If you want to extract the 'data' `df$data[,-1]` or `df[['data']][,-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely remove `links`:

```
df$links <- NULL
```

Remove columns 1 and 2 from `included`:

```
df$included[,c(1, 2)] <- NULL
```

Remove columns 3 and 4 from `data`:

```
df$data[,c(3, 4)] <- NULL
```

For a working example, see below with iris and mtcars:

```
exr <- list(iris = iris, mtcars = mtcars)
head(exr$mtcars)
|                  |  mpg| cyl| disp|  hp| drat|    wt|  qsec| vs| am| gear| carb|
|:-----------------|----:|---:|----:|---:|----:|-----:|-----:|--:|--:|----:|----:|
|Mazda RX4         | 21.0|   6|  160| 110| 3.90| 2.620| 16.46|  0|  1|    4|    4|
|Mazda RX4 Wag     | 21.0|   6|  160| 110| 3.90| 2.875| 17.02|  0|  1|    4|    4|
|Datsun 710        | 22.8|   4|  108|  93| 3.85| 2.320| 18.61|  1|  1|    4|    1|
|Hornet 4 Drive    | 21.4|   6|  258| 110| 3.08| 3.215| 19.44|  1|  0|    3|    1|
|Hornet Sportabout | 18.7|   8|  360| 175| 3.15| 3.440| 17.02|  0|  0|    3|    2|
|Valiant           | 18.1|   6|  225| 105| 2.76| 3.460| 20.22|  1|  0|    3|    1|

exr$mtcars[,c(1,2)] <- NULL

head(exr$mtcars)
|                  | disp|  hp| drat|    wt|  qsec| vs| am| gear| carb|
|:-----------------|----:|---:|----:|-----:|-----:|--:|--:|----:|----:|
|Mazda RX4         |  160| 110| 3.90| 2.620| 16.46|  0|  1|    4|    4|
|Mazda RX4 Wag     |  160| 110| 3.90| 2.875| 17.02|  0|  1|    4|    4|
|Datsun 710        |  108|  93| 3.85| 2.320| 18.61|  1|  1|    4|    1|
|Hornet 4 Drive    |  258| 110| 3.08| 3.215| 19.44|  1|  0|    3|    1|
|Hornet Sportabout |  360| 175| 3.15| 3.440| 17.02|  0|  0|    3|    2|
|Valiant           |  225| 105| 2.76| 3.460| 20.22|  1|  0|    3|    1|
```

Comment: this definitely did the trick, because $included is still in the Dataframe, would the data structure still be considered as DF or a list ?

Comment: `df` is a list of dataframes, and so `df$included` is a dataframe, but `df` itself is a list